# Definition of direction of directional light in custom shader of Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am currently implementing a custom shader with Three.js and still don't understand the definition of direction of `THREE.DirectionalLight`.

For example, if I add a directional light source in this way:

```
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( "white", 1. );
directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
scene.add( directionalLight );
```

the directional light is defined to illuminate from `(0,0,0)` to (0,1,0)``. I have played with the built-in material to confirm this, but I am still not confident about how the direction is passed to a shader.

In my custom material, I am passing the uniforms to a shader by using `THREE.RawShaderMaterial` with `THREE.UniformsLib["lights"]`. In the shader, I am writing

```
#if NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0

    struct DirectionalLight {
        vec3 direction;
        vec3 color;
    };

    uniform DirectionalLight directionalLights[ NUM_DIR_LIGHTS ];

#endif
```

to use the uniforms of `DirectionalLight`.

Intuitively, I assumed that `vec3 direction` is the vector pointing from the light source to the target, which should be `(0,-1,0)`. However, if I output the value of direction in GLSL code, the direction was `(0,1,0)`, which is the vector pointing from the target to the light source.

Is there any place documenting this definition? It would be great if someone can point me out how Three.js is passing uniforms of `DirectionalLight` to a shader in the source code. Then, I would be able to understand how the Three.js's developers have decided to define the direction of `DirectionalLight`.

Comment: It is a unit vector in camera space pointing from the target to the light.  [Source code L2343-L2346](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L2343-L2346). three.js r.84

Comment: Thank you for specifying the source code. I have finally understood how they are passed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at a diagram for blinn-phong shading:

[image]

And we will notice that the L vector is pointing away from the surface, and towards the light source. If we say that it is intuitive for a normal to be pointing away from the surface, the light vector should to in order to make the math work.

Consider a point light, which has no direction but is a point in space. How would you calculate the direction to a specific fragment or vertex? You might be inclined to say that the light is shining towards the fragment:

```
 fragLightDir = fragPos - lightPos
```

But it should be

```
 fragLightDir = lightPos - fragPos
```

> the directional light is defined to illuminate from (0,0,0) to (0,1,0)``.

Actually not, it's more like the light source is at (0,1,0) pointing towards the origin (since dir light is just a direction).

I'm not actually sure how shadows work, i think they're actually independent of the dir light, and that it's just an orthographic camera that can be moved around. Without shadows, it doesn't make much sense to 'move' the light, rather you position it somewhere, it always shines towards the origin, and gets normalized under the hood.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. I was thinking that the light direction is the direction to which the light is propagating. Your answer solved my confusion.